# WPF ListBox - getting the indices of the selected items

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Since the WPF ListBox does not have a SelectedIndices property, is there any way to obtain this information?

Note that using IndexOf is not possible since there may be duplicate items.

Edit: I wish to avoid code-behind - I can pass a single item to a view model from a context menu like this:

```
<MenuItem Header="Process Items" Command="{Binding UpOneCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedIndex}"/>
```

However, I am looking for a way to pass all selected indices.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this via a simple view model that wraps around your data that you'd like to display in the `ListBox`. This wrapper exposes an additional boolean `IsSelected` property:

```
class SelectionWrapper<TModel> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private boolean _isSelected;
    private TModel _model;

    public SelectionWrapper(TModel model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }

        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public TModel Model
    {
        get { return _model; }

        set
        {
            _model = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged ...
}
```

Instead of adding your data directly to an `ObservableCollection`, wrap your data using the wrapper view model.

Write a `DataTemplate` for your `ListBox` that binds a `CheckBox` to this property and add another control(s) to show the remaining part of your view model/model (like a `Label` that shows a string).

One way to query the selected items could be via a read-only property that uses simple LINQ:

```
public IEnumerable<YourItemWrapperViewModel> SelectedIndicies
{
    get
    {
        return YourItemsCollection.Where(item => item.IsSelected);
    }
}
```

You should call the `PropertyChanged` event for `SelectedIndicies` everytime `IsSelected` of any of the items in your collection changed. To solve this observe your `ObservableCollection` for added/deleted items:

- In case an item is added register a handler for `PropertyChanged` of the wrapper view model.
- In case an item has been deleted unregister the handler.

Comment: If you can't follow my steps above: http://thatcsharpguy.com/post/multiselect-listview-mvvm-en/

Comment: But this means I have to display a checkbox which I don't want - right?